# asp.net mvc - membership provider

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

For my **ASP.NET MVC** app, I just find dealing with unique-identifiers harder, so I have added my own field to ASPNET_USERS table - UserIdInt (which is actually a bigint!) So most of user operations use userIdInt as reference.

Anyway, I am debating between two approaches:

1)When a user logs in, look up from the database and store the userIdInt in a session variable and any-time session variable slips away, re-look it up and put it back in session variable. (It's okay to use sessions in MVC app, right?)

2)Any time an operation needs to be performed, simply pass userName to database and take care of UserIdInt at database side by doing joins and such on ASPNET_Users table any time an operation from user needs to be performed.

I am heavily leaning towards 1)... but I want to make sure I am on right track.

Comment: You're probably better off asking at stackoverflow.com